# JSON converting result in java failed (JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray)

Tags: java, android, json

I have a problem with the JSON result of my PHP script. I can't extract this result in JAVA. There is the error below :

```
Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value 
{"3":[{"date":"25\/07\/2011","descr":"Une colloque bla bla","numColloque":"1","titre":"Une colloque"}],
 "2":[{"mail":"jm@dvaid.fr","descr":"truc truc","nom":"Une personne","tel":"0600000000","numPersonne":"1"}],
 "1":[{"lien":"http:\/\/www.irdes.fr","numTypeActu":"1","date":"25\/07\/2011","titre":"Une actualité récente","numActu":"1"}],
 "7":[{"numEtablissement":"1","specialite":"STG","mention":"une mention","modalite":"BTS","titre":"Un titre de formation","numFormationCours":"1"}],
 "6":[{"numEtablissement":"1","numEnseignement":"1","titre":"Cours de bla bla","numEnseignant":"1"}],
 "5":[{"date":"31\/07\/2011","descr":"Université paris descartes dans le 1-ème arrondissement de Paris","numEtablissement":"1","libelle":"IUT Paris DESCARTES"}],
 "4":[{"numDocument":"1","lienPDF":"http:\/\/www.irdes.com","date":"25\/07\/2011","numTypeDocument":"1","descrRapide":"un glossaire qui regroupe du bla bla","nom":"un document de glossaire"},
      {"numDocument":"2","lienPDF":"http:\/\/www.irdes.com","date":"25\/07\/2011","numTypeDocument":"2","descrRapide":"Une synthèse parlant d'un truc","nom":"Une synthèse"}],
 "9":[{"lien":"http:\/\/www.irdes.fr","descr":"un séminaire sur le blabla","date":"25\/07\/2011","heure":"14h30","nom":"Un séminaire","numSeminaire":"1"}],
 "8":[{"numPublication":"1","lienPDF":"http:\/\/www.irdes.com","date":"25\/07\/2011","numTypePublication":"1","titre":"Une publication"},
      {"numPublication":"2","lienPDF":"http:\/\/www.irdes.com","date":"25\/07\/2011","numTypePublication":"2","titre":"un titre de publication"},
      {"numPublication":"3","lienPDF":"http:\/\/www.irdes.com","date":"25\/07\/2011","numTypePublication":"3","titre":"un titre"}]} 

of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

The syntax of my result is simple :

```
{"Object1":[{"id":"value"},{"id":"value"}],
 "Object2":[{"id":"value"},{"id":"value"}],
 ...
}
```

My JAVA script for the extraction (ligne error : with an **):

```
result=sb.toString();
**JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);**
for (int i=1;i<=9;i++){
    JSONObject typeUpdateObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    extraction(typeUpdateObject, i);
}
```

This is not the right method for this extraction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers by Chris and Charles are correct and you should look over the [JSON specification](http://json.org/).  That said, I believe the following is what you're looking for.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(""+i);
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length();j++)
        extraction(arr.getJSONObject(j), i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code Matt :) just for the second for, it's j variable :) (j<arr.length())

Answer (score 7):

You are getting confused between objects and arrays.

Both the code samples you posted are objects `{}` whereas arrays are `[]`.

The structure you have is: `{[{}]}`

Whereas your parsing code snippet is expecting: `[{}]`

There is a big hint in the error:
    type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

An object is an unordered list of key:value pairs.

```
{ // object
    "key" : "value",
    "key2" : "another value"
}
```

An array is an ordered (indexed) list of values:

```
[ // array
    "value1",
    "value2"
]
```

Comment: I understood that, but my PHP code encode an array, an array of Objects values. Thanks for your explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how a JSON should look,

as Charles said Object {}  Arrays [], this is a handy cheat sheet for learning JSON

**object**
{}
{ members }
**members**
pair
pair , members
**pair**
string : value
**array**
[]
[ elements ]
**elements**
value 
value , elements
**value**
string
number
object
array
true
false
null